# Neo4j apoc.load.json() Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to load a Json file into neo4j server using Apoc procedure, for which I am using the following query:

```
call apoc.load.json("file:///Users\adnan\Desktop\test.json") yield value Return value
```

The Following error is shown:

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input 'a': expected
>   '\', ''', '"', 'b', 'f', 'n', 'r', 't', UTF16 or UTF32 (line 1, column
>   36 (offset: 35)) "call
>   apoc.load.json("file:///Users\adnan\Desktop\test.json") yield value
>   Return value"

If i load the same file through the URL it works. I don't get whats wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the forward slash ('/') as the path separator in URIs passed to neo4j, instead of the back-slash ('\').